# preg_match_all multiple results on same line

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

The results I am trying to extract data from are in the following format

```
<a href="anime/hackroots">.hack//Roots</a> <img src="images/video.png" border=0 width=16 height=16 alt="Flash video available" title="Flash video available"> (8) <br><a href="anime/hacksign">.hack//SIGN</a>
```

I am trying to extract the location and name of each anime using the following code:

```
preg_match_all('#<a href="anime/(.*)">(.*?)</a>#', $content, $match);
```

However, the results stretch across many lines, with 50+ results on each line, and I am not able to fetch a single match using that method, so was wondering what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What you are doing wrong is using regex for HTML parsing.

Comment: Asked a thousand times, it's just that you wrote the regex to do so. Learn about ["Greediness" in PCRE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). Also take care which characters (esp. whitespace) the dot "`.`" matches.

Comment: `#<a href="anime/(.*)">(.*?)</a>#s`; the [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: Also, change your first `(.*)` to `(.*?)` to make it [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).  Or use a more specific character class saying "anything but `"`" (`([^"]*)`).

Answer (score 0):

Use lazy matcher. Set matching should also help

```
<?php

$string = '<a href="anime/hackroots">.hack//Roots</a> <img src="images/video.png" border=0 width=16 height=16 alt="Flash video available" title="Flash video available"> (8) <br><a href="anime/hacksign">.hack//SIGN</a>';

$pattern = '#<a href="anime/(?P<location>.*?)">(?P<description>.*?)</a>#';

$matches = null;
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

https://eval.in/139332